Bertini-type theorem for reducedness
Let $f_1, ... f_r$ be homogeneous polynomials in $k[x_0, ... x_n]$ such that $X = Proj(k[x_0, ... x_n] / (f_1, ... f_r))$ is reduced and has pure dimension $d$.
Is there an open set $U$ of $\mathbb{P}^{n \vee}_k$ such that for all $H \in U$, $X \cap H$ is reduced of dimension $d-1$? $X \cap H$ is defined as follows:
Let $i$ be such that $H \in D(y_i)$, so $H$ is a point in $Spec(k[y_0/y_i, ... y_n /y_i])$. Let $a_j$ be the image of $y_j/y_i$ in $k(H)$, (so $a_i = 1$).
$X \cap H$ the closed subscheme of $\mathbb{P}^n_{k(H)}$ given by the equations $(f_1, ... f_r, a_0 x_0 + ... + a_n x_n)$.
I think this is true but I don't know how to prove it. Following the proof of Bertini's theorem in Vakil's Foundations of Algebraic Geometry, section 13.4 :
I want to define a doubly homogeneous ideal of $k[x_0, ... x_n, y_0, ... y_n]$ that cuts out a closed set in $\mathbb{P}^n_k \times_k \mathbb{P}^{n \vee}_k$ that corresponds to the "bad" points. Intuitively, it should be $(x, H) : x $ is a point on $V(f_1, ... f_r)$ and $H$, and either $X \cap H$ is not dimension $d-1$, or $x$ is a non-reduced point of $X \cap H$.
I don't know how to find polynomial equations to express this condition. For "$x$ is non-reduced", I think we consider the nilradical of $k[x_0, ... x_n, y_0, ... y_n]/ (f_1, ... f_r, a_0 x_0 + ... + a_n x_n)$, and that one nilpotent element is nonzero in the local ring at $x$.
For "$X \cap H$ is not dimension $d-1$", I think this says that $H$ contains a generic point of an irreducible component of $X \times_k k(H)$, but I don't know how to express this in terms of polynomials.

Nowadays you just need to check a couple axioms and Serre's conditions $R_a$ and $S_b$ satisfy these axioms for $a,b \geq 0$. Since reducedness is $R_0 + S_1$ it is indeed a Bertini property.

An analogue for finite fields following Poonen's Bertini theorem was also recently established for finite fields as well.
